# Approval of iPhone app with UIWebView subclass

Tags: iphone

Apple does say in the documentation about the fact that they do not want us to subclass UIWebview. After reading a lot of posts, I think it is the internals of the Webview that makes it complicated and it may be the reason apple has said so.

Iam looking to subclass this. Is there anyone who has faced this problem before?

Comment: If it's listed as unsupported in the documentation, then it's fair game for rejection. Why do you want to subclass UIWebView?

Comment: I doubt it would cause a rejection but I think it would be fragile and stand a good chance to break on iOS updates.  There may also not be easy in the same manner of subclassing NSString.

Comment: (I don't think subclassing NSString would be easy either - it's tied very closely to CFString in ways we can only imagine!). I'd try to use a category to extend it instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several applications on the AppStore that are subclassing UIWebView (to get the location of a tap on iOS3.x) and I had no issue with validation process regarding this ...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use APIs that are not documented then you should be fine (assuming you don't break any of their other UI guidelines).

However, a bigger question is what are you trying to do that you can't achieve any other way than subclassing? Apple's advice is spot on; UIWebView will be very complicated nd you will probably get something wrong because you don't know it's internal workings.

If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to point you in the direction of a better method :)

Comment: I am actually trying to override the default behaviour of doubletap on  a UIWebview. I want to invoke selection of text when we doubletap a word on the UIwebview. The only way it seems I can do it is to write my own set of classes to create a magnifying class and selection tools and assign them to the touches methods on the subclass

Comment: You could try attaching a UIView to the UIWebView, make it the same size. Attach a GestureRecogniser to this view to grab double taps. Everything else caan be passed down the responder chain and the uiwebview will handle it. This won't extend the webview but should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have also got another way to tap the event using  the method of creating a subclass of UIWindow. I wanted to check if there is any other simple way of invoking text selection on double tap

Comment: Could you do it in javascript in the html itself? (just an idea; I have no idea if it would work well or not!)

Comment: From what I have researched, we can get what is selected on the UIWebview in javascript and we can change the html based on that but there is no way to create a selection from javascript to UIWebview. If I get anything working will post it here... Thank you.

Comment: You can fake a message out of a UIWebView by going to a URL and catching it in your UIWebViewDelegate - if you use a predefined url like `message://click?item_id=1` you can read the id from the url and this tells your app which item was clicked on (don't forget to tell the web view _not_ to navigate to that URL as well!)